# Cleaning tag soup from the View in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, html-helper

I want to remove if-statements from my View, but I'm having problems with predefined controls like Html.DropDownList.

For example, I have an DropDownList that in some case contains empty selection (or in other words.. possibility to Not select something) and other case is that there is no empty selection.

```
<% if (Model.IsCreateEmptySelectionSet)
{ %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("InternalVariableTypeList", Model.InternalType, "-- select internal variable type --")%>
<% } %>
<% else
{ %>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("InternalVariableTypeList", Model.InternalType)%>
<% } %>
```

So, I would like create helper that would create correct DropDownList, but when I create my own helper I can't access Html.DropDownList. How is it used in correct way?

Comment: `Html.DropDownList("InternalVariableTypeList", Model.InternalType, Model.IsCreateEmptySelectionSet ? "-- select internal variable type --" : "")` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks!

That would work and it would be much cleaner, but it would not solve the actual problem which is that I can't access Html.<something> in my own helper.

DropDownList was just an example and in that case difference between two lines is very tiny, but in real scenario there could be multiple differences which can't be handled with ternary operator

Comment: Did you use namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html` in your helper class? it is required to use these helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html helpers could be used to clean the tag soup and also make your code more testable:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomDropDown<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool isCreateEmptySelectionSet)
    {
        if (isCreateEmptySelectionSet)
        {
            return htmlHelper.DropDownList("InternalVariableTypeList", selectList, "-- select internal variable type --");
        }
        return htmlHelper.DropDownList("InternalVariableTypeList", selectList);
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
<%= Html.CustomDropDownList(
    "InternalVariableTypeList", 
    Model.InternalType, 
    Model.IsCreateEmptySelectionSet)
%>
```

Remark: `CustomDropDownList` is a very poorly chosen name, pick a more adapted one to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed! I didn't have "this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper" and therefore I didn't have access to the DropDownList